# How to define a function that counts how many times a word is repeated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to make a function that outputs as a list of how many times it is in the sentence

```
def words(text:str,number:int):
    text=text.split()
    for freq in text:
        print(freq,"," text.count(freq)
```

I know this isn't correct, because i want the output to look like

```
[(cat,4),(dog,10),(pig,3)]
```

I am unsure how to approach this problem.
I also want it to only allow it to count the amount of different repeated words with the number assigned to the function

Comment: return a list rather than just printing?

Comment: yes, i put print because that is the only way i know how to code this but i know i am wrong

Comment: there are countless tutorials to learn the basics from.

Answer (score 1):

After splitting the string I created a set with unique entries. With `re.findall` you can find the count of every word in the text. The function `words` returns a dictionary with the word as key and the count as value.

```
import re

def words(text:str):
    textsp = text.split()
    unique = set(textsp)
    count = []
    for word in unique:
        count.append(len(re.findall(word, text)))
        
    out = dict(zip(unique, count))
    return out
    
te = "cat dog cat pig dog dog pig cat"

print(words(te))
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use sets - https://realpython.com/python-sets/

This is a possible approach using sets:

```
s = "cat cat cat cat dog dog dog".split()
def words(s):
    counter = []
    for i in set(s):
        counter.append((i,s.count(i)))
    return counter
print(words(s))
```

Comment: hi! this one seems to work, but it counts the amount of letters instead of the words. my instructor is going to be putting random words into my function to test it so i did text.split() instead.

Comment: Oh if you need any more help let me know :)